# php regex square brackets and commas

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to capture the text within the square brackets and commas in the string below.

```
$_['text_1']      = 'text_2 %d to %d of %d (%d text)';
```

I have a regex for square brackets

```
preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]*\]/",$string,$matches); //all strings with brackets
```

but need two regex for

1. text_1
2. text_2 %d to %d of %d (%d text)

Comment: your example features parenthesis instead of square brackets, which might explain why it doesn't work as intended

Comment: Where are the commas?

Comment: Why not just use `'([^']+)'` [like this](https://regex101.com/r/xZ2rO6/1) if your "commas" are always bordering to brackets and there are no escaped `'` in string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `"/\[[^\]]*\]/"` only matches substrings like `[.[.[..]`.

You can easily get the values using

```
(?|\['([^][]*)']|'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)')
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dI8sL2/4), your values will be in Group 1.

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/YX8xnB):

```
$re = "/(?|\\['([^][]*)']|'([^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\])*)')/"; 
$str = "\$_['text_1']      = 'text_2 %d to %d of %d (%d text)';"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

The regex contains 2 alternatives with 2 capturing groups that have Index 1 since a branch reset grouping `(?|..|..)` is used. The 2 alternatives match:

- `\['([^][]*)']` - a literal `['`, followed with 0 or more characters other than `]` and `[` up to `']`
- `'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)')` - any substring inside single quotes that may contain any escaped sequences.

Or a safer one that will also allow any `[` or `]` inside the first group (i.e. if you have `$_['P[O]ST']` though I guess it is unlikely):

```
(?|\['([^']*(?:'(?!])[^']*)*)'\]|'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)')
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/dI8sL2/3)

Comment: Thank you sir. I get all value I need with your regex and substr substr($matches[0][0], 2, -2);

Comment: No idea why you access the 0th elements, you just need the 1st.